# python: choose element from a list following a certain probability

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, probability

I'm looking for a python function that would allow me, given a list and a certain probability, to return only the elements that "pass" the lottery. For instance:

```
my_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']
my_probability = 0.66 # The probability for an element to stay in the list
winner = THE_RANDOM_FUNCTION(my_list, my_probability)
print(winner)
>> ['A', 'C'] # Could be a different result but that only an example
```

So I want the function to do a lottery (with the given probability) for every element in the list and to keep it in the result list if it passes the lottery.

Is there such function in the standard library or should I implement it?

Comment: What's your logic for involving that probability?

Comment: What does 0.66 mean?

Comment: The probability for an element to "stay" in the sublist

Comment: @Kasramvd I add more precision to the question

Comment: @mel - Could you please provide more detail on " probability for an element to "stay" in the sublist  ".

Comment: @McGrady 0.66 means 66/100. Or 33/50.

Comment: I guess, the OP means a binomial trial.

Comment: @SashantPardeshi Well it's a binomial trial, every element in my list got a probability of 0.66 to pass or fail

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you mean you want to choose or not choose each element,
with the given probability. Here are a couple of simple solutions:

```
filter(lambda x: random.random() < my_probability, my_list)

[x for x in my_list if random.random() < my_probability]
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a classic binomial trial to me.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: my_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']

In [3]: prob = 0.66

In [4]: mask = np.random.binomial(1, prob, len(my_list))

In [5]: selected = [elem for keep, elem in zip(mask, my_list) if keep]

In [6]: selected
Out[6]: ['A', 'B']
```

Or you can go the pure Numpy-way, if you don't need the final result to remain a list

```
In [7]: my_arr = np.array(my_list)

In [8]: my_arr[mask.astype(bool)]
Out[8]: 
array(['A', 'B'], dtype='<U1')
```